# Why fsockopen: Failed to enable crypto on smtp.gmail.com

Tags: php, email

On my Apache/2.4.37 server I use PHP 7.4.8 and 1.1.1c-15.el8 but when I use fsockopen on smtp.gmail.com(I tried both ports: 465 and 587) I get this error:

```
Warning: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number in /var/www/public_html/mail.php on line 9
Warning: fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto in /var/www/public_html/mail.php on line 9
Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to tls://smtp.gmail.com:587 (Unknown error) in /var/www/public_html/mail.php on line 9
```

I use cloudflare, but there the MX records are set.

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe this is related: [link](https://support.microfocus.com/kb/doc.php?id=7003300#:~:text=Identity%20Manager%20Error%3A%20SSL3_GET_RECORD%3Awrong%20version%20number,-Document%20ID%3A7003300&text=The%20error%20message%20displayed%20in,the%20driver%20shim%20is%20running.). Note: I just googled `SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number`.

Comment: I suspect that the problem come from a system update, because I had openssl-1.1.1c-2.el8, and we had no problem using fsockopen on smtp.gmail.com. Now the openssl version is openssl-1.1.1c-15.el8.